# How to define Storyboard for Border in XAML style

Tags: windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

Is there a way to define Storyboard for TargetType Border in XAML Style?
Here is what I am trying to achieve:

```
<Style x:Key="MyBorderStyle" TargetType="Border">

    <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">

        <Setter.Value>
            <VisualStateGroup>
                <VisualStateGroup.States>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                        <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PaperDark}"/>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="StrokeThickness">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="2"/>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="StrokeDashArray">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="3, 3"/>
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:0.200" Value="3, 3"/>
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:0.400" Value="3, 3"/>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="StrokeDashOffset">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="3"/>
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:0.200" Value="0"/>
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:0.400" Value="3"/>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup.States>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>        
</Style>
```

But this is not working.

I also tried couple of more approaches but couldn't get it to work.
I want to define this style in my MyStyles.XAML and then use it in MainPage.XAML like:

```
<Border Style="{StaticResource MyBorderStyle}">
Some code...
</Border>
```

Please help.

Comment: You did the correct thing not using discrete Storyboards here

Answer (score 2):

Just wrap it in a `Grid` and define the states there. If you want to reuse it, then wrap it in a `UserControl` instead. Like this (which works):

```
<Grid>
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="VisualStateGroup">
            <VisualState x:Name="VisualState0">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background)" Storyboard.TargetName="border">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="Red"/>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FF2E00FF" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="border" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderThickness)" Storyboard.TargetName="border">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <Thickness>5</Thickness>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.CornerRadius)" Storyboard.TargetName="border">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <CornerRadius>15</CornerRadius>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="VisualState1">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FF2EFF00" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="border" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background)" Storyboard.TargetName="border">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF0017FF"/>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderThickness)" Storyboard.TargetName="border">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <Thickness>25,5</Thickness>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.CornerRadius)" Storyboard.TargetName="border">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                <CornerRadius>45</CornerRadius>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="234" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="303" Margin="75,75,0,0"/>
</Grid>
```

Remember, use Blend to define your Visual States.

Read: http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2013/11/windows-81-how-to-use-visual-states-in.html

Best of luck!

Comment: As a quick reminder, Thickness cannot be animated with anything other than Frames.

Comment: Thanks @Jerry :)
I am actually trying to get Marquee type of border style (border consisting of dash and keeps moving, like the one we get when we select element in Photoshop).
I was able to get it for stroke of xaml element Rectangle :)

but not sure how to do it for border, since I don't see StrokeDashArray or StrokeDashOffset for border.

Comment: I know. I answered your other question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19800928/how-to-show-marquee-style-border-around-object-in-xaml-c-sharp-windows-8/20105439#20105439 only Drawing objects have those properties.

Comment: okies. It would have been nice to see those properties with Border though. Thanks Jerry

Comment: @ashishnirkhe A rectangle inside a Border is basically the same thing. <Border><Grid><Rectangle /><YourStuff></Grid></Border>

Comment: Right. 
But my task is to provide Border with Marquee style to other consuming classes, which can add any type of element in it.
e.g.: One class might add Textbox, one might add Image, one might add some custom control etc. :)

Comment: You could do this with an attached property for this. But WinRT does not have adorners which is what you really want here.

Comment: This question has been answered. I recommend marking it so. If you want to ask another question, do it.

Answer (score 0):

Why you need to use it inside Style ?
Just give a name to the Storyboard & declare it under Resources.

```
  <Page.Resources>
      <Storyboard x:Name="Bordersb" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke" Storyboard.TargetName="PART_BORDER">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PaperDark}"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="StrokeThickness">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="2"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="StrokeDashArray" Storyboard.TargetName="PART_BORDER">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="3, 3"/>
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:0.200" Value="3, 3"/>
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:0.400" Value="3, 3"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="StrokeDashOffset" Storyboard.TargetName="PART_BORDER">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="3"/>
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:0.200" Value="0"/>
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:0.400" Value="3"/>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
         </Storyboard>
  </Page.Resources>

<Border x:Name="PART_BORDER>
 Some code...
</Border>
```

In code behind you can start your storyboard by

```
 Bordersb.Begin();
```

Comment: I kind of tried this option earlier, but didn't work.
I was wondering if the Target Properties "Stroke" or "StrokeDashArray"
etc are available for XAML element <Border>

I know it's available for Rectangle, and it works for Rectangle.

Comment: @ashishnirkhe yea , Border don't have Stroke , StrokeThickness etc.. properties. Use BoderThickness ,BorderBrush etc.. properties instead.

Comment: @asitis But he's wanting them to create a specific effect.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you would need to use [`DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.doubleanimationusingkeyframes.aspx) and [`EnableDependentAnimation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.doubleanimationusingkeyframes.enabledependentanimation.aspx) instead?

Actually scratch that. The visual states need to be defined as part of the template and so you simply need to redefine the entire template. Otherwise - yes you'd need to have `Storyboards` defined in XAML or code behind and run them manually instead of relying on visual states.

Maybe you could define a resource and modify the visual states in code behind at runtime if you really don't want to change the entire template, but that sounds kind of hacky and might be of questionable reliability.

Comment: Except for that a Border does not have a Template